# An example of a sequence which does not have any subsequence with a finite limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

> Find and example of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ which does not contain any subsequences having a finite limit.

I've been thinking of the following seqeunce:
$$
x_n = \sin(n)\cdot\sin(\sqrt{3}n)
$$

But is that true? Also what are other examples of such sequences?

Comment: Natural numbers $1,2,3,...$? No subsequence is Cauchy, hence convergent?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг oh my, shame on me

Comment: Remember, every bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence. Therefore, your sequence being bounded does not have a convergent subsequence. The best bet is to take an unbounded sequence where the distance between any two terms is greater than some fixed number.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thank you! it's crystal clear now

Comment: Great. You can now answer this question yourself and close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $|x_n| \to \infty$ will do.

By Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem others wont: if $|x_n| \not \to \infty$, there is $M$, such that you can find a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ that is bounded by $M$. Then you can find a converging subsequence of that subsequence (and hence of the original sequence).

---

**EDIT**: By the way, if we think of the [one point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of $\mathbb{R}$ where we add $\infty$ in, then every sequence has a converging subsequence in this space (which is homeomorphic to circle). So this also shows that the only way to **have no subsequence with finite limit** is to make that converging subsequence that is quaranteed to exists in the compactified space to have limit $\infty$. Well I guess you still have to make the above argument to show that we must have $|x_n|\to \infty$ (i.e $x \to \infty$ in the compactified space).

Answer (score 8):

The example in the OP is wrong. This can be shown by [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) which states that every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence.

Now if we consider:
$$
x_n = \sin(n)\sin(\sqrt{3}n)
$$
its clear that the sequence is bounded by $[-1, 1]$. Hence it contains a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Upvoted. Good job.

Comment: Take for example $n=1, 8,77,    146,    721,   5270,  19492 , 33714 ,148357, 263000, 674357$ and you get $ 0.8305543, 0.9506199, 0.9883301, 0.9962933, 0.9996635, 0.9997120, 0.9998930,
 0.9999708, 0.9999954, 0.9999987, 0.9999999$